# form linked to google maps with jquery

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-directions-api

I am trying to design a travel agency site. such that when a client enters his destination.    example:

```
from: London
To: Dubai
```

then click submit the google jquery map will show the link between this two countries on that same page.

I have been trying to get around it for a while but it seems so difficult but I beleive some one must have done or carried out such before.

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps API V3 is the solution you are looking for. Have a look at Direction API of Google Maps API V3, that will help you to develop a site like which you have specified.

Have a look at the following example. Might be this will help you out.

[Google Sample Code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints)

[Example 2](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#directions_simple)